# How to write xpath with contains ID using TestCafé?

Tags: xpath, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, browser-automation

Need to take the dynamic ID using "contains" keyword in TestCafé selector.

**html:**

```
<div id="content-body-14269002-17290547">
```

**xpath:**

```
//div[contains(@id,"content-body")]
```

I would like to **write above xpath in TestCafé** Selector
Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is not supported. [See here](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/1178#issuecomment-350249305).

A good workaround I can recommend to handle such cases is to use [xpath-to-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xpath-to-css) package.

Also, you can just create a CSS selector for this case, CSS Selector for partial `id` match will be:

```
div[id*='content-body']
```

Hope this is helpful. Good luck!